# Getting "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.addAll" when deploying to WebLogic

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, weblogic12c

I have a number of Spring Boot Maven projects. They are pretty simple wrappers of REST Services for `Angular/React` UI clients. I develop in Eclipse using integrated Tomcat-9 and then deploy to WebLogic-12c [WLS] on Linux. I use `spring-boot-starter-parent` version-`2.2.4.RELEASE` with the following components:

- spring-boot-starter-web
- spring-security-config
- spring-security-web

The projects/webapps are very similar and all work fine in WLS, although we've had some classpath conflicts, but were able to resolve them using something like this in `WEB-INF/weblogic.xml` as recommended by Oracle:

```
              <wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>false</wls:prefer-web-inf-classes>
              <wls:prefer-application-packages>
                     <wls:package-name>org.slf4j</wls:package-name>
                     <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
              </wls:prefer-application-packages>
```

The last project, however, would not deploy to WLS despite being equipped with the same weblogic.xml. It runs fine in `Tomcat` and `local WLS`, but fails on the server due to the following:

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: 


 Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap.addAll(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/util/List;)V


        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadSpringFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:140)

        at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactoryNames(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:119)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:429)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getSpringFactoriesInstances(SpringApplication.java:421)

        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>(SpringApplication.java:268)
```

I installed two versions of WLS on my local PC - 14c, and then 12c - just like what we run on the Linux server. The project in question runs locally on both without any issues.

This "bad" project has exact same dependencies as the "good" ones. As a matter of fact, the contents of `WEB-INF/lib` are exactly the same. So far I couldn't find what makes this project so special that Spring fails to initialize.

So here's my question. What could possibly cause this WLS deployment issue and ways to resolve it.

Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After I added the `<wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>` there would be no issue at all ... if I first have **deleted** the failed deployment. I however used the **Install** option on WL console to upload the new war file and then **Update** to redeploy. Apparently WL has an issue with that approach in case one is trying to update a deployment that failed in the first place.